# CRUD using form: Updating

Tags: forms, symfony, file-upload, crud

I've been getting errors when I press update.
I'm using the same code as adding.
I think it may be the picture upload that is causing the problem.

Here's the error:

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) string.
>   You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.

My Controller:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request ,$id)
{
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $forum = $em->getRepository("ForumBundle:Forum")->find($id);
  $forum->setModifiee(new \DateTime('now'));
  $form = $this->createForm(ForumType::class, $forum);
  $form->handleRequest($request);
  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $file = $form['image']->getData();
    $file->move("images/", $file->getClientOriginalName());
    $forum->setImage("images/" . $file->getClientOriginalName());
    $em->persist($forum);
    $em->flush();
    return $this->redirectToRoute('forum_show');
  }
  return $this->render("@Forum/Sujet/Update_topic.html.twig", array("form" => $form->createView()));
}
```

My Form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  $builder->add('titre')
          ->add('tags')
          ->add('image', FileType::class,array('attr' => array(
                'class'=>'form-control'
              //'class'=>'btn btn-default btn-file'
          )))
          ->add('blog',TextareaType::class)
          ->add('Ajouter',SubmitType::class,array('attr' => array(
                'class'=>'theme_button color3 wide_button'
          )));
}
```

These are my includes:

```
namespace ForumBundle\Controller; 
use blackknight467\StarRatingBundle\Form\RatingType; 
use ForumBundle\Form\RateType; 
use ForumBundle\Entity\Commentaire; 
use ForumBundle\Entity\Forum; 
use ForumBundle\Entity\Rating; 
use ForumBundle\Form\CommentaireType; 
use ForumBundle\Form\ForumType; 
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType; 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; 
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
```

Comment: can you show us the import section of your classes? Usually this error occur when you don't import the appropriate class in the import section, symfony try to guest it self which class should be use

Comment: @NDZIEPatrickJoel

Comment: I incorporated you includes from the comment section into your question.

Comment: Can you please provide the full code of  your form Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Symfony documentation : [How to upload file](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html), you have to set a File Object into Image setter, not a string. That'a why you have this error :

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) string.
>   You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.

The rigth way to accomplish this is to set a new File instance to your image on your controller object, like this :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
// ...

public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $forum = $em->getRepository("ForumBundle:Forum")->find($id);
  $forum->setModifiee(new \DateTime('now'));
  $form = $this->createForm(ForumType::class, $forum);
  $form->handleRequest($request);
  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
  {
     $file = $form['image']->getData();
     $file->move("images/", $file->getClientOriginalName());

     $forum->setImage("images/" . $file->getClientOriginalName());

     $forum->setImage(new File($this->getParameter('images_directory').'/'.$forum->getImage()));

     $em->persist($forum);
     $em->flush();
     return $this->redirectToRoute('forum_show');
  }
}

// ...
```

The parameter `images_directory` have to be set in the services.yml file, according to the symfony's documentation :

```
# config/services.yaml

# ...
parameters:
   # depending of your symfony version 
   images_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/web|public/uploads/images'
```

Another way is to use an uploader service or a dedicated bundle like : [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) or [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle)

Hope this help and have a nice day !!!

Answer (score 0):

In symfony 2.8 in updateAction just  correct define fileType for $id
I think it should look like this:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request ,$id) { 

     $id->setImage( 
            new File($this->getParameter('images_directory').'/'.$id->getImage()
     ));
```

...